# Java 8: get average of more than one attribute

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

In the following class:
I want to get average of foo and bar in `List<HelloWorld> helloWorldList`

```
@Data
public class HelloWorld {
    private Long foo;
    private Long bar;
}
```

**OPTION 1: JAVA**

```
Long fooSum, barSum;
for(HelloWorld hw: helloWorldList){
    fooSum += hw.getFoo();
    barSum += hw.getBar();
}
Long fooAvg = fooSum/helloWorldList.size();
Long barAvg = barSum/helloWorldList.size();
```

**OPTION 2 : JAVA 8**

```
Double fooAvg = helloWorldList.stream().mapToLong(HelloWorld::foo).average().orElse(null);
Double barAvg = helloWorldList.stream().mapToLong(HelloWorld::bar).average().orElse(null);
```

Which approach is better ?
Is there any better way to get these values ?

**Answer edit**: This question has been marked duplicate but after reading comments from bradimus i ended up implementing this:

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;
public class HelloWorldSummaryStatistics implements Consumer<HelloWorld> {
    @Getter
    private int fooTotal = 0;
    @Getter
    private int barTotal = 0;
    @Getter
    private int count = 0;

    public HelloWorldSummaryStatistics() {
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(HelloWorld helloWorld) {
        fooTotal += helloWorld.getFoo();
        barTotal += helloWorld.getBar();
        count++;
    }

    public void combine(HelloWorldSummaryStatistics other) {
        fooTotal += other.fooTotal;
        barTotal += other.barTotal;
        count += other.count;
    }

    public final double getFooAverage() {
        return getCount() > 0 ? (double) getFooTotal() / getCount() : 0.0d;
    }

    public final double getBarAverage() {
        return getCount() > 0 ? (double) getBarTotal() / getCount() : 0.0d;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
            "%s{count=%d, fooAverage=%f, barAverage=%f}",
            this.getClass().getSimpleName(),
            getCount(),
            getFooAverage(),
            getBarAverage());
    }
}
```

**Main Class:**

```
    HelloWorld a = new HelloWorld(5L, 1L);
    HelloWorld b = new HelloWorld(5L, 2L);
    HelloWorld c = new HelloWorld(5L, 4L);
    List<HelloWorld> hwList = Arrays.asList(a, b, c);
    HelloWorldSummaryStatistics helloWorldSummaryStatistics = hwList.stream()
            .collect(HelloWorldSummaryStatistics::new, HelloWorldSummaryStatistics::accept, HelloWorldSummaryStatistics::combine);
    System.out.println(helloWorldSummaryStatistics);
```

Note: As suggested by others if you need high precision BigInteger etc can be used.

Comment: Note: the first one would be much better if you used `long` instead of `Long`, to avoid allocating unnecessary objects. Also, watch out for the integer division.

Comment: The first one is better as it only interates the list once.

Comment: If you are going to use a `Stream`, write your own [reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html) (Look at the [`Averager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html#collect) example.)

Comment: @bradimus thank you. Averager example is more readable. If you have more examples please mention them.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27925742/how-to-compute-average-of-multiple-numbers-in-sequence-using-java-8-lambda)

Comment: @bradimus in the answers of link mentioned in above comment they do not implement consumer interface, but in Averager example they do. Is implementing consumer interface recommended ?

Comment: I'm not sure about your values and your goal, but second one will give you more precise answer. But this has nothing to do with streams.

Comment: Write a Collector.  Base it on IntSummaryStatistics.

Answer (score 2):

The answers/comments you got so far don't mention one advantage of a streams-based solution: just by changing `stream()` to `parallelStream()` you could turn the whole thing into a multi-threaded solution.

Try doing that with "option 1"; and see how much work it would need.

But of course, that would mean even more "overhead" in terms of "things going on behind the covers costing CPU cycles"; but if you are talking about **large** datasets it might actually benefit you.

At least you could very easily see how turning on parallelStreams() would influence execution time!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find average value in list of integers it is better to use classic approach with iterating.
Streams have some overhead and JVM has to load classes for stream usage. But also JVM has JIT with lots of optimizations.

Please beware of incorrect banchmarking. Use [JMH](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjdk.jmh)
Streams are good and effective when your iteration operation is not such a simple thing as two integers sum.
Also streams allow you to parallelize code. There is no direct criteria when parallelize is better than single thread. As for me - if function call takes over 100ms - you can parrallelize it.

**So**, if your dataset processing takes >100ms try `parallelStream`

If not - use iterating.

P.S. Doug Lea - "[When to use parallel streams](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/html/StreamParallelGuidance.html)"

Answer (score 0):

> Which approach is better ?

When you say "better", do you mean "closer to the sample's  true average" or "more efficient" or what? If efficiency is your goal, streams entail a fair amount of overhead that is often ignored. However, they provide readability and conciser code. It depends upon what you're trying to maximize, how large your datasets are, etc.

Perhaps rephrase the question?